# What's the easiest way to turn the non-transparent parts of any image file into a single svg path?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there an automated way to turn the **non-transparent** parts of any png file to a single svg path?

#### So the starting png file might look something like this...

[image]

#### And the resulting `SVG` path might look something like this...

[image]

---

I have searched for a free online or open source tool that can do an ok job of this with no luck...

[image]

Comment: http://vectormagic.com/

Comment: Vector magic did exactly what I needed and then said $300 if you want to save it.  Nope.

Comment: someone voted to close this because this question has already been asked and answered.  Please link me to the answer that is not vector magic and I'll happily close it. I wouldn't be asking on stack overflow if I had $300 to blow.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry. They used to let you save.  I hadn't realised that had stopped.  An alternative is the potrace tool.  Or you can use Inkscape, which has potrace built in.

Comment: Thanks Paul I'll try those

Comment: I'm considering putting my own tool out on github that only handles this single case (generating a single svg path around non-transparent pixels)   This seems like it would fill such an obvious need especially in a flat design world I was surprised there weren't tools that did this in an obvious way at least.

Comment: In GIMP, use [alpha to selection](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-layer-alpha-selection-replace.html), and then use [selection to path](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-using-paths-and-selections.html), then [export path as SVG](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-using-paths-and-svg.html).  For future reference, this question would have been on topic on [Graphic Design Exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AmeliaBR you just saved me a ton of time / money with this simple workflow that Graphic Designers probably don't even think twice about but UI developers have no clue.  I think there is enough overlap to include the question in both places but most of all **Thanks for the correct answer**

Comment: @DaveAlger Glad you got it working.  Stack Overflow may only be for *programming* questions, but sometimes the much easier solution is to use an existing tool rather than programming your own!